# Cannot reset an network interfaces without a reboot

Tags: networking, service, interface

I have edited the `/etc/network/interfaces` file and I use the `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`.

After restart, the `eth1` interfaces don't setup properly. I need a hard reboot to enable this configuration. Meanwhile the command line hints: *Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces*.

Am I using the run command to restart network interfaces?

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.87
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: So if you restart, and login through a shell, what is the actual state of your network configuration?  Can you run `ip addr; ip route` after a restart, save the output, and post that output?

Comment: Hi @Zoredache `ip route` seems to return the WAN ip address of my local network such as `61.194.136.130`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "new" way of resetting interfaces is trough the ifdown and ifup command:

```
ifdown eth1 
ifup eth1
```

Try this command and see if the eth1 is getting set up properly. 
If this still fails you can always try to check your logfiles to see if anything suspicious is happening there.